# Animating a path in SVG in Firefox using transform-origin 50% 50%

Tags: firefox, animation, svg, css-transforms

I have the following SVG which produces a polygon with 2 cogs inside it, one large and one small:

```
        <a href="#nogo" class="services__support">
            <svg viewBox="0 0 124 111" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
                <polygon fill="#FBB040" points="32.373,107.329 2.519,55.622 32.373,3.916 92.082,3.916 121.93,55.622 92.082,107.329 "></polygon>
                <g class="correct">
                    <g class="large-cog">
                        <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M27.964 34.342c0.365-0.637 0.239-1.393-0.276-1.695l-1.265-0.909 -1.259-0.909c-0.518-0.297-0.76-0.853-0.395-1.483 0.37-0.638 0.973-0.707 1.49-0.407l1.414 0.639 1.417 0.638c0.521 0.3 1.338-0.076 1.706-0.706 0.517-0.521 0.69-1.387 0.271-1.813l-0.982-1.2 -0.986-1.2c-0.423-0.426-0.514-1.025 0.006-1.541 0.52-0.521 1.116-0.43 1.541-0.005l1.206 0.978 1.2 0.985c0.423 0.426 1.187 0.347 1.708-0.173l0.244-0.138c0.633-0.37 0.904-1.087 0.607-1.609l-0.638-1.414 -0.635-1.419c-0.304-0.518-0.234-1.121 0.401-1.484 0.633-0.37 1.19-0.125 1.489 0.392l0.907 1.261 0.909 1.262c0.299 0.522 1.19 0.604 1.827 0.24 0.709-0.19 1.295-0.85 1.14-1.432l-0.25-1.533 -0.248-1.533c-0.157-0.577 0.065-1.142 0.775-1.333 0.706-0.188 1.183 0.191 1.334 0.772l0.553 1.446 0.553 1.453c0.155 0.582 0.994 0.896 1.704 0.707 0.732 0 1.466-0.489 1.466-1.088l0.157-1.546 0.158-1.542c0-0.6 0.361-1.089 1.092-1.089 0.733 0 1.094 0.489 1.094 1.089l0.157 1.542 0.155 1.546c0 0.599 0.597 0.815 1.33 0.815l0.272 0.076c0.707 0.189 1.409 0.142 1.56-0.436l0.555-1.451 0.55-1.451c0.151-0.582 0.629-0.959 1.338-0.768 0.706 0.191 0.931 0.75 0.771 1.333l-0.245 1.532 -0.25 1.534c-0.155 0.576 0.415 1.272 1.121 1.463 0.638 0.364 1.52 0.309 1.82-0.208l0.905-1.26 0.909-1.257c0.305-0.523 0.855-0.767 1.489-0.397 0.638 0.364 0.704 0.969 0.403 1.485l-0.638 1.419 -0.636 1.42c-0.299 0.517 0.071 1.332 0.707 1.702 0.515 0.516 1.379 0.691 1.806 0.266l1.202-0.979 1.206-0.984c0.426-0.425 1.021-0.512 1.539 0.005s0.429 1.115 0.006 1.541l-0.984 1.206 -0.985 1.2c-0.423 0.425-0.27 1.313 0.246 1.83 0.366 0.635 1.155 1.026 1.675 0.727l1.418-0.636 1.415-0.637c0.52-0.3 1.121-0.23 1.487 0.402 0.368 0.636 0.124 1.191-0.393 1.49l-1.259 0.907 -1.262 0.908c-0.521 0.3-0.608 1.196-0.236 1.828 0.184 0.713 0.849 1.293 1.425 1.144l1.533-0.252 1.532-0.25c0.583-0.159 1.144 0.071 1.334 0.771 0.189 0.714-0.188 1.187-0.768 1.344l-1.451 0.543 -1.452 0.555c-0.581 0.157-0.896 0.996-0.707 1.708 0 0.734 0.488 1.468 1.086 1.468l1.547 0.153 1.545 0.157c0.596 0 1.086 0.364 1.09 1.095 0 0.731-0.488 1.092-1.09 1.092l-1.545 0.157 -1.547 0.159c-0.6 0-1.121 0.729-1.121 1.46 -0.19 0.709 0.089 1.547 0.671 1.704l1.448 0.549 1.452 0.549c0.58 0.158 0.96 0.632 0.768 1.339 -0.188 0.706-0.754 0.931-1.328 0.77l-1.535-0.243 -1.534-0.25c-0.575-0.158-1.273 0.415-1.462 1.127 -0.37 0.63-0.315 1.512 0.206 1.811l1.256 0.909 1.263 0.906c0.521 0.306 0.762 0.854 0.396 1.49 -0.37 0.637-0.97 0.703-1.489 0.41l-1.413-0.644 -1.421-0.636c-0.515-0.299-1.336 0.071-1.701 0.704 -0.521 0.523-0.695 1.386-0.271 1.806l0.981 1.209 0.981 1.201c0.424 0.426 0.516 1.021-0.006 1.539 -0.518 0.518-1.115 0.43-1.538 0.006l-1.206-0.98 -1.202-0.982c-0.426-0.426-1.309-0.275-1.828 0.24 -0.636 0.369-1.029 1.156-0.73 1.68l0.64 1.408 0.64 1.42c0.297 0.521 0.229 1.119-0.403 1.488 -0.638 0.367-1.192 0.127-1.493-0.395L59.2 64.895l-0.907-1.258c-0.303-0.521-1.194-0.604-1.832-0.238 -0.708 0.184-1.29 0.848-1.135 1.426l0.248 1.533 0.249 1.531c0.156 0.584-0.066 1.148-0.774 1.338 -0.711 0.186-1.185-0.189-1.339-0.771l-0.551-1.447 -0.553-1.455c-0.153-0.578-0.995-0.895-1.704-0.703 -0.733-0.006-1.468 0.484-1.468 1.082l-0.157 1.551 -0.155 1.545c0 0.598-0.36 1.082-1.094 1.082 -0.732 0-1.09-0.484-1.09-1.082l-0.158-1.545 -0.155-1.551c0-0.598-0.733-1.119-1.468-1.119 -0.704-0.197-1.543 0.086-1.698 0.668l-0.549 1.453 -0.549 1.451c-0.157 0.582-0.632 0.953-1.342 0.76 -0.708-0.183-0.927-0.748-0.773-1.326l0.248-1.533 0.25-1.535c0.153-0.58-1.024-1.205-1.732-1.395 -0.634-0.365 0.303-0.518 0 0l-2.117 1.395 -0.909 1.262c-0.299 0.523-0.852 0.764-1.485 0.398 -0.64-0.371-0.707-0.967-0.405-1.49l0.636-1.412 0.641-1.42c0.298-0.516-0.072-1.334-0.71-1.703 -0.516-0.521-1.381-0.697-1.805-0.271l-1.206 0.984 -1.2 0.978c-0.425 0.424-1.022 0.516-1.544 0 -0.519-0.518-0.43-1.121-0.004-1.543l0.981-1.203 0.983-1.207c0.426-0.42 0.275-1.305-0.241-1.827 -0.364-0.632-1.153-1.029-1.675-0.731l-1.417 0.638 -1.416 0.642c-0.52 0.297-1.122 0.229-1.488-0.408 -0.367-0.638-0.124-1.185 0.396-1.491l1.258-0.909 1.261-0.901c0.521-0.305 0.13-1.578-0.235-2.214 -0.19-0.706 0.58-0.151 0 0l-2.487-0.506 -1.529 0.244c-0.58 0.157-1.146-0.063-1.336-0.771 -0.188-0.713 0.19-1.181 0.768-1.339l1.452-0.551 1.452-0.547c0.58-0.159 0.896-1.001 0.704-1.708 0-0.735-0.485-1.47-1.084-1.47l-1.545-0.155 -1.546-0.153c-0.603 0-1.088-0.366-1.088-1.098 0-0.736 0.485-1.095 1.088-1.095l1.546-0.153 1.545-0.157c0.599 0 1.122-0.733 1.122-1.462 0.189-0.712-0.091-1.545-0.669-1.702l-1.452-0.549 -1.45-0.555c-0.583-0.151-0.959-0.624-0.771-1.332 0.191-0.713 0.754-0.929 1.334-0.779l1.534 0.252 1.533 0.244c0.582 0.157 1.202-0.287 1.396-0.996M48.169 24.2c-10.393 0-18.81 8.424-18.81 18.812 0 10.393 8.417 18.815 18.81 18.815 10.393 0 18.812-8.422 18.812-18.815C66.981 32.624 58.562 24.2 48.169 24.2z">
                        </path>
                    </g>
                </g>
                <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M60.565 43.012c0 6.906-5.594 12.498-12.498 12.498 -6.902 0-12.494-5.592-12.494-12.498 0-6.902 5.592-12.498 12.494-12.498C54.971 30.514 60.565 36.109 60.565 43.012zM48.201 35.2c-4.351 0-7.874 3.529-7.874 7.882 0 4.35 3.523 7.881 7.874 7.881 4.356 0 7.88-3.53 7.88-7.881C56.081 38.729 52.557 35.2 48.201 35.2z">
                </path>
                <g class="correct">
                    <g class="small-cog">
                        <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M63.473 70.325c0.268-0.459 0.177-1.014-0.202-1.232l-0.919-0.664 -0.919-0.664c-0.384-0.217-0.562-0.627-0.292-1.086 0.27-0.465 0.707-0.516 1.091-0.295l1.032 0.463 1.037 0.467c0.378 0.219 0.975-0.053 1.242-0.518 0.382-0.377 0.512-1.012 0.2-1.32l-0.716-0.881 -0.725-0.873c-0.309-0.318-0.375-0.752 0.006-1.129 0.38-0.379 0.819-0.314 1.126-0.004l0.882 0.713 0.879 0.725c0.311 0.307 0.872 0.248 1.25-0.127l0.177-0.104c0.464-0.273 0.661-0.793 0.444-1.176l-0.466-1.031 -0.465-1.041c-0.222-0.379-0.173-0.813 0.291-1.08 0.465-0.271 0.868-0.098 1.091 0.281l0.665 0.924 0.663 0.922c0.218 0.381 0.875 0.443 1.338 0.172 0.518-0.133 0.94-0.619 0.83-1.045l-0.179-1.113 -0.184-1.125c-0.116-0.42 0.046-0.836 0.565-0.975 0.517-0.135 0.865 0.139 0.976 0.566l0.401 1.055 0.407 1.066c0.11 0.418 0.722 0.652 1.241 0.512 0.535 0 1.074-0.355 1.074-0.791l0.114-1.129 0.114-1.133c0-0.439 0.264-0.793 0.799-0.793 0.535 0 0.801 0.354 0.801 0.793l0.112 1.133 0.114 1.129c0 0.436 0.437 0.596 0.972 0.596l0.199 0.053c0.519 0.137 1.03 0.104 1.143-0.32l0.401-1.061 0.407-1.061c0.108-0.426 0.459-0.701 0.975-0.561 0.516 0.141 0.679 0.547 0.566 0.973l-0.181 1.121 -0.185 1.121c-0.108 0.424 0.309 0.93 0.824 1.072 0.467 0.266 1.106 0.227 1.322-0.154l0.667-0.918 0.665-0.926c0.219-0.373 0.626-0.555 1.091-0.287 0.46 0.27 0.513 0.707 0.293 1.088l-0.467 1.031 -0.468 1.039c-0.215 0.381 0.055 0.98 0.521 1.248 0.376 0.379 1.005 0.504 1.316 0.193l0.879-0.711 0.882-0.723c0.309-0.311 0.746-0.373 1.125 0.004 0.378 0.381 0.313 0.816 0.004 1.125l-0.718 0.881 -0.718 0.883c-0.31 0.309-0.205 0.955 0.177 1.332 0.266 0.467 0.842 0.756 1.224 0.539l1.035-0.469 1.037-0.469c0.382-0.219 0.818-0.168 1.086 0.293 0.268 0.469 0.095 0.871-0.287 1.088l-0.921 0.67 -0.921 0.664c-0.382 0.215-0.446 0.877-0.177 1.338 0.14 0.514 0.621 0.939 1.047 0.826l1.119-0.18 1.119-0.184c0.426-0.109 0.835 0.047 0.975 0.568 0.142 0.518-0.136 0.861-0.562 0.975l-1.061 0.402 -1.063 0.404c-0.421 0.113-0.655 0.727-0.513 1.244 0 0.539 0.352 1.076 0.793 1.076l1.127 0.115 1.13 0.115c0.44 0 0.795 0.264 0.795 0.799 0 0.537-0.354 0.799-0.795 0.799l-1.13 0.113 -1.127 0.111c-0.441 0.004-0.821 0.537-0.821 1.076 -0.136 0.514 0.065 1.125 0.49 1.236l1.059 0.406 1.061 0.4c0.429 0.115 0.702 0.461 0.563 0.98 -0.138 0.516-0.551 0.678-0.976 0.563l-1.119-0.182 -1.12-0.176c-0.425-0.119-0.931 0.299-1.07 0.814 -0.268 0.465-0.23 1.111 0.151 1.328l0.921 0.664 0.921 0.662c0.382 0.219 0.557 0.625 0.289 1.088 -0.268 0.469-0.706 0.518-1.088 0.301l-1.035-0.469 -1.037-0.467c-0.379-0.219-0.978 0.055-1.245 0.516 -0.378 0.381-0.504 1.01-0.194 1.322l0.716 0.881 0.716 0.879c0.313 0.311 0.378 0.746-0.004 1.127 -0.378 0.375-0.813 0.311-1.125 0l-0.88-0.717 -0.879-0.713c-0.31-0.311-0.959-0.207-1.337 0.174 -0.462 0.268-0.751 0.844-0.531 1.223l0.463 1.033 0.469 1.039c0.216 0.383 0.169 0.82-0.296 1.088 -0.464 0.266-0.869 0.094-1.09-0.289l-0.665-0.922 -0.665-0.92c-0.213-0.381-0.868-0.447-1.336-0.174 -0.514 0.135-0.942 0.619-0.83 1.043l0.183 1.121 0.182 1.119c0.117 0.42-0.048 0.838-0.564 0.975 -0.521 0.137-0.863-0.137-0.977-0.563l-0.403-1.061 -0.401-1.059c-0.114-0.43-0.729-0.658-1.246-0.517 -0.539 0-1.076 0.354-1.076 0.789l-0.114 1.133 -0.115 1.125c0 0.445-0.26 0.799-0.793 0.799 -0.537 0-0.801-0.354-0.801-0.799l-0.116-1.125 -0.114-1.133c0-0.435-0.535-0.816-1.068-0.816 -0.521-0.141-1.13 0.068-1.246 0.49l-0.401 1.061 -0.403 1.061c-0.112 0.424-0.456 0.701-0.979 0.561 -0.514-0.143-0.679-0.551-0.561-0.973l0.179-1.121 0.181-1.127c0.114-0.416-0.743-0.873-1.259-1.018 -0.465-0.266 0.217-0.379 0 0l-1.551 1.029 -0.665 0.914c-0.216 0.381-0.623 0.561-1.086 0.295 -0.466-0.273-0.516-0.709-0.293-1.094l0.46-1.033 0.469-1.035c0.216-0.381-0.054-0.979-0.518-1.244 -0.38-0.381-1.012-0.512-1.32-0.203l-0.882 0.721 -0.875 0.723c-0.31 0.31-0.752 0.369-1.126-0.01 -0.382-0.379-0.316-0.811-0.006-1.121l0.719-0.883 0.718-0.875c0.307-0.309 0.201-0.963-0.177-1.342 -0.268-0.465-0.847-0.746-1.226-0.529l-1.035 0.465 -1.035 0.465c-0.38 0.219-0.818 0.17-1.084-0.293 -0.27-0.467-0.093-0.871 0.285-1.094l0.921-0.662 0.923-0.664c0.378-0.219 0.094-1.148-0.172-1.609 -0.142-0.521 0.422-0.119 0 0l-1.821-0.375 -1.116 0.184c-0.427 0.109-0.836-0.049-0.976-0.568 -0.138-0.518 0.134-0.867 0.557-0.975l1.066-0.41 1.061-0.395c0.423-0.113 0.653-0.73 0.512-1.25 0-0.535-0.354-1.072-0.791-1.072l-1.129-0.115 -1.13-0.113c-0.438 0-0.795-0.262-0.795-0.799 0-0.537 0.356-0.801 0.795-0.801l1.13-0.113 1.129-0.115c0.437 0 0.82-0.533 0.82-1.07 0.138-0.518-0.065-1.125-0.487-1.24l-1.064-0.402 -1.061-0.404c-0.424-0.113-0.697-0.459-0.56-0.977 0.136-0.518 0.55-0.68 0.975-0.572l1.123 0.186 1.116 0.184c0.427 0.115 0.881-0.217 1.02-0.732M78.246 62.92c-7.595 0-13.751 6.154-13.751 13.746 0 7.598 6.156 13.748 13.751 13.748 7.592 0 13.748-6.15 13.748-13.748C91.994 69.075 85.837 62.92 78.246 62.92z">
                        </path>
                    </g>
                </g>
                <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M87.301 76.666c0 5.041-4.089 9.137-9.134 9.137 -5.043 0-9.132-4.096-9.132-9.137 0-5.047 4.089-9.135 9.132-9.135C83.212 67.532 87.301 71.62 87.301 76.666zM78.268 70.956c-3.18 0-5.758 2.58-5.758 5.762 0 3.18 2.578 5.758 5.758 5.758 3.18 0 5.757-2.578 5.757-5.758C84.025 73.536 81.448 70.956 78.268 70.956z">
                </path>
            </svg>
        </a>
```

I am trying to rotate the cogs 360degress on hover, focus etc but this just doesn't work in Firefox. I have tried to implement the fix which I found here: http://jsfiddle.net/4h3xL/1/ but I can't seem to get this working in Firefox.

My CSS code is as follows:

```
    .services {
        color:$body-colour;

        a {
            display:block;
        }

        svg {
            display:block;
            margin:0 auto;
            width:30%;

            @include mq($from:tablet) {
                width:40%;
            }
        }
    }

    /* ================================
       Animation Keyframes
       ================================ */

    @keyframes spin {
        100% { transform:rotate(360deg); }
    }


    // Service icon hover animations
    svg {
        .correct {
            transform: translate(62px, 55.5px);

            circle, path, line, polygon  {
                transform:translate(-62px, -55.5px);
            }
        }
    }

    .services a {
        .large-cog {
            transform-origin:50% 50%;
            transform:rotate(0);
        }

        &:hover, &:focus, &:active {
            .large-cog {
                animation:spin 6s linear infinite;
            }
        }
    }
```

Wrapping the path etc in groups with the class "correct" worked for other animations which were misbehaving in Firefox, but for this particular SVG icon it just won't work.

Does anyone have any ideas, or can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Any help is much appreciated.

Cheers
Jp

Comment: Firefox does not currently support transform-origin with percentages.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Figured it out using pixels instead of percentages for the transform-origin

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out using pixels instead of percentages for the transform-origin